# In Javascript, when looping through an array of objects, how do I send each element's name to the console?

Tags: javascript, arrays, element

How do I spit out the element's *name* (each object's name) to the console as the array of objects iterates?

I've searched online, in various posts and threads, but I cannot find the answer to this. Nor is there anything on this in the properties/methods for Array that I can see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
let card1 = {
  question:'1+1?',
  answer:'2'
}

let card2 = {
  question:'1+2',
  answer:'3'
}

let card3 = {
  question:'1+3',
  answer:'4'
}

let card4 = {
  question:'1+4',
  answer:'5'
}

let card5 = {
  question:'1+5',
  answer:'6'
}

let cards = [card1,card2,card3,card4,card5];

cards.forEach(function(card){
  console.log(card.name);
  console.log(card.question);
  console.log(card.answer);
});
```

Here's my fiddle of the above:
https://jsfiddle.net/JaredHess/arLmnz72/7/

I keep hoping there's a method like `card.name` or `card.id` (but those don't exist).

For example, when it loops to the first element in the array, I want it to show `card1`, like this:

```
card1
"1+1?"
"2"
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Objects don't have any reference to the variable they're assigned to. An object can be assigned to multiple variables.

Comment: Just give the objects a `name` property -- don't use global variables like this.

Comment: Thank you! @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the cards in an array instead of defining them as individual variables.

If you want to create a custom `name` property for each card, then you certainly can — but if you just want a template name like `"name 1"`, `"name 2"`, etc., then you don't need to define the name in each object in the array. Instead, you can create and add the names in a [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) using each card's index, like this:

```js
const cards = [
  {question:'1+1?', answer:'2'},
  {question:'1+2', answer:'3'},
  {question:'1+3', answer:'4'},
  {question:'1+4', answer:'5'},
  {question:'1+5', answer:'6'},
].map((card, index) => ({...card, name: `card${index + 1}`}));

cards.forEach(card => console.log(card));
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCGAnAJhGBeGBtAUDGA3gI4CuAptAJbgBcA5AIwDUDA-HQDQzyQDuZiegCY6AXw55CpClGph6zEVx4R+gugGYxE-MXJVajJluV8B9ACzbJemXIVMrp1eboBWa7ukH5Rj87V6ADZrAF0AOgBbeAAHAAo4hBQuSjBkMgAPAEoMAD4YOIJw4qTkLjB4SLIaGAADUoASAlT0jJgmGAZRWtEsrIBuHBxSiHCAMxBEAFF4YAALRKRkPLhwCBAAGzJwjZAAc0WUPsGgA)

Comment: Thank you @jsejcksn! That makes sense.

Comment: @Jared I'm glad it does! I like exploring approaches which reduce typing.